# Active Directory Pass Through Authentication for Apache Intranet Web-Application (PHP, JS)

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I've builded some Intranet Web-Applications, which run on an Docker Container (Ubuntu-Host) with Apache and PHP.

The current Authentication is based on the Active Directory (NOT Azure, On-Premise Domain Controller)
It's a login-page where you insert your userPrincipalName and Password.
I'm using the PHP LDAP Module and the ldap_bind function for this.

But the user is already logged in with his Windows (or Active Directory) Account on the client-machine.
So I was wondering, if I could build an Single-Sign-On- (or more precise a Pass-Through-)Authentication.

For IIS-Server this is pretty simple ...

I tried to find something, but I guess I'm not using the correct terminology.

You find a lot of stuff for configuring an Azure-AD, but as I said we don't use Azure.
I tried "PHP AD Passthrough Authentication", "PHP Kerberos", "PHP NTLM", "Webapplication Active Directory Passthrough" and similiar things for JS.
(Because you are logged in on your client-machine, you probably have to send some data from the client and use this on server-side)
But this doesn't give me the results I need.

It seems than you can use the ldap_sasl_bind function (with the parameter "GSSAPI"), but I can't figure out what exactly I got to do.

Has anyone expierience in this and can help me?

I wouldn't mind if the Login-Page has an extra button "Login with Windows Credentials", which would trigger the Pass-Through-Authentication. Full automation is nice to have, but I'd be happy if my users can login without entering "username" and password.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, you can use modules such as [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi) or olders **mod_auth_kerb** or **mod_auth_ntlm**. If you still support it, NTLM is the easier, like on IIS I would say. You also have similar modules for Apache for Windows.

Keep in mind that some of the NTLM or KERB mechanisms just simply require your sites to be registered in  the "**intranet trusted zone**" of your browser. It's maybe a part of your problem.

Finally, as you have a Windows AD on premise infrastructure, you could perhaps ask your administrators if they plan to use an **IAM solution**, which you could then query via **OIDC/Oauth2 or SAML**. For this, you can have a look at the super easy PHP lib [Jumbojett PHP OpenID Connect](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP)